# About java client connected to Spring websocket

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websocket

I write a simple websocket server by help of [springboot-websocket guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("*");
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

}

@Controller
public class P2PMessageController {

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public P2PMessage sayHello(P2PMessage message){
        P2PMessage msg=new P2PMessage();
        msg.setText("hello");
        return msg;
    }
}
```

My questions:
I can establish the connection with `ws://server/endpoint`,but how can I send a message to `/app/hello` and subscribe on `/topic/greetings` with a java client but not a javascript client.  
I could not find an appropriate java websocket api for the client.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I find an implementation for stomp in java [stilts](http://stilts.projectodd.org/stilts-stomp-client/).This provides subscription.